# How to avoid SetState in componentWillMount

Tags: reactjs, react-native, setstate

I have a Welcome Screen I want to show to users only once. It works I use AsyncStorage to save the token. It changes state of ShowWelcomeSlides, so I can make a condition. But I have an error message. I really don't know where I can update state if not in componentWillMount. Any idea ?

Warning: Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState, replaceState, or forceUpdate on an unmounted component. This is a no-op.

```
  componentWillMount() {
    this._renderWelcomeSlidesWithAsyncStorage().done();
  }

  _renderWelcomeSlidesWithAsyncStorage = async () => {
    let value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('AlreadyVisited');

            if (value==='true'){
              this.setState({ShowWelcomeSlides: 'false'});
              console.log('token is present')
            }else{
              this.setState({ShowWelcomeSlides: 'true'});
              console.log('token is not present');
              this._setValue();
            }
        }; 

      onSlidesComplete = () => {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Home');
      }

  render(){

    if (this.state.ShowWelcomeSlides==='true'){
        return(
        <Slides data={SLIDE_DATA} onComplete={this.onSlidesComplete} />
      );
    }return(
     <SkipWelcome />
    );
```

Comment: it's okay if it is async

Comment: Alright, so I can move on with the app, it will not cause problem ?

Comment: In my experience, this warning occurs when your async method is completing and the component is being unmounted. This can be a tricky condition to track down as, from a UI perspective, it appears that everything is working. I would check your flow and make sure the component isn't getting mounted and unmounted somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the warning is for the use of componentWillMount. You should call _renderWelcomeSlidesWithAsyncStorage in componentDidMount to be certain that your app mounted.

Comment: With componentDidMount, the warning is still here. Do you think it will be an issue for App Store ?

Comment: Are you sure about that? Maybe you're setting state from your app before it's mounted.Is the snippet complete?

Comment: What does this. _setValue do? Maybe it's called after the component is unmounted.

Comment: `_setValue = async () => {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('AlreadyVisited', 'true');
  };`

Comment: it stores the token if it does not exist yet

Comment: I'm not exactly sure because the app code is not complete but you might be calling "onSlidesComplete" before "_setValue" resolves which would justify the warning. The issue here is that your app is dependent on AsyncStorage response and you somehow need to cancel it / check if your component is mounted before resolving the AsyncStorage promise. See : https://discuss.reactjs.org/t/cancel-async-fetch-on-unmount/3272 for more info. There is a deprecated way of checking "isMounted" that could be of some use (instead of using redux for your app)

Comment: Actually `componentWillMount` is calling `this._renderWelcomeSlidesWithAsyncStorage().done()`. This is calling "_setValue". Then, when the component renders slides, the function onSlidesComplete gets called to navigate to a different screen

Comment: Could you post more of your code? For example the Slides component in order to see where onComplete is called from specifically.

Comment: I see you're not calling .done() on this._setValue(). Maybe this is why you're still seeing the warning?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150006/discussion-between-sonia-and-daniel-andrei).